# how to add footer in tcpdf

Tags: pdf, footer, tcpdf

I am using tcpdf library to generate the pdf and i have to add a copy right text in footer but all the text is printing in a single line and only the middle section is visible I am using

```
$htmlbody="Copyright © 2014 XYZ. All rights reserved. Specifications subject to change"
                        . " without notice. XYZ and the XYZ logo are trademarks or registered trademarks"
                        . " of XYZ. All other trademarks used or mentioned herein belong to their respective owners";
        $this->Cell(100, 10, $htmlbody , 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
```

and the pdf generated looks like this 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a multi lines text you can use [`MultiCell()`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#aa81d4b585de305c054760ec983ed3ece)

```
$this->MultiCell(100, 0, $htmlbody."\n", 0, 'C');
```